# Using multiple parameters in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to figure out the best way to use multiple parameters in `Ruby`. The problem is that I am using two types of parameters: `Event` and `User`. Sometimes the method needs one `User`:

```
postAccept.replaceVariables(sally)
```

Sometimes it needs two `Users`:

```
deleteGuest.replaceVariables(sally, tom)
```

Sometimes it needs an `Event` and two `Users`:

```
addUserToEvent.replaceVariables(mEvent, tom, sally)
```

And last, sometimes it needs one `Event` and one `User`:

```
addnonbookable.replaceVariables(event1, carl)
```

Here is what I am doing currently in regard to the method:

```
def replaceVariables(*event)

    if event.size <=2

        if event[0].include?('entryId')
            event1 = event[0]
            my = event[1]
        else
            my = event[0]
            their = event[1]
        end
    else
        event1 = event[0]
        my = event[1]   
        their = event[2]
    end
            ...
```

The problem is, I can't figure out a way to differentiate between the `user` and the `event`. In the example above, I tried to determine if the object has a specific key, or value, but I get `NoMethodError`.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or show me a way to keep things dynamic and flexible?

Comment: This is really bad style. You should write your methods in a way that they accept a small and rather static number of arguments. You should rather implement multiple methods for the different call patterns, normalize the values and then call another method which implements the actual logic if required.

Comment: Why does the method sometimes need different types of objects?

Comment: The reason that I am doing it this way is because it is the simpler way to do it. The method is replacing a number of different environment variables. Currently the method is 220 lines of code. If I break it into 2 methods, that will double.

Comment: Whoa ... 1. That's way too many lines. 2. The linecount won't double, you just need one big routine and a couple of 1-line alternate front-ends. *Or 3.* just take a hash in the first place: f :user1 => tom, :event1 => whatever

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def replace_variables(*args)
  events = args.select{|a| a.is_a? Event}
  users = args.select{|a| a.is_a? User}
  #now you have 2 arrays and can manipulate them
  #...
end
```

Tin Man suggested implementation in 1 line:

```
def replace_variables(*args)
  events, users = args.group_by{ |p| p.class }.values_at(Event, User)
  #now you have 2 arrays and can manipulate them
  #...
end
```

Comment: `a.is_a? Event` is probably better since that allows subclasses of Event to still be treated as an Event.

Comment: The two lines of this method can be replaced with `events, users = params.group_by{ |p| p.class }.values_at(Event, User)`

Answer (score 1):

Check if the first argument is an event. If it is, then it is the only event, and the rest are users, and you can shift out the event. Otherwise, all of them are users.

```
def replaceVariables(*users)
  event = nil
  if users.first.is_a? Event
    event = users.shift
  end
  # ...
end
```